# Award expired bounty to an answer that already existed

Tags: support

I offered a bounty on my question [What formulae does the Geolocation Distance use?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32585/what-formulae-does-the-geolocation-distance-use) after an answer was already posted and accepted.

I chose the "Reward existing answer" option thinking that was exactly what I wanted to do.
[image: Reward existing answer]

Now it turns out the bounty expired and didn't get automatically awarded to the existing answer.

Is there an super admin power that can award that bounty now that it has expired past the grace period?

I could offer the same bounty again, but I would need to double the Rep to 300 in addition to the 150 that was deducted from the first bounty.

To be fair to StackExchange, there were several notifications during the bounty grace period that I missed until it was too late.